# how to pass parameter from backend to frontend if don't use hidden field control or any display:none html item

Tags: jquery, asp.net, html

For example, if I want to pass session value to the frontend and use as a variable value in javascript, is there a way that don't use hidden field to pass the value?

Comment: Um? Generate a script that assigns the desired value to a global Javascript variable as a literal?

Comment: `<script type="text/javascript">var variable = <?php echo $variable ?></script>`
?

Comment: I don't think global variable is a good choice if just use the parameter once

Comment: I'm not use php, thanks though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple way:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        var value = '<%=Session("sessionkey") %>';
 </script>
```

Drawback is that "value" javascript variable will always be string. Event if object stored in session under "sessionkey" is not string. So better way is to use javascript serializer:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        var value = <%=(New System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer()).Serialize(Session("sessionkey"))%>;
  </script>
```

Note: you have to reference System.Web.Extensions assembly to use JavaScriptSerializer. Code above is in VB language. C# equivalent would be:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            var value = '<%=Session["sessionkey"] %>';
  </script>
```

and

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            var value = <%=(new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer()).Serialize(Session["sessionkey"])%>;
 </script>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Besides session, is there another way to pass parameter from back to frontend?

Comment: Yes. If value stored on server is not stored in session (which in most cases), then you do not need to use session at all. Just make a variable on server that is protected or public (private won't work), and use it like `var value= '<%=myServerVariable %>';`

Answer (score 0):

You can pass them throw ajax:

```
var hidden_vars;
var ajax = $.ajax({
    url: "get_vars.asp",
    dataType: "json"
});
ajax.success(function( response ) {
    hidden_vars = response.vars;
});
```

and then **get_vars.asp**

```
{
    "vars": {
        "var1": "something",
        "var2": "else"
    }
}
```

Then you can access your variables using `hidden_vars`

```
alert(hidden_vars.var1); // something
```

Else I don't know? But interested!

Andreas